# DataSnap standalone HTTPS server (EXE) - OpenSSL support for TLS v1.2

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, openssl, datasnap

I have a standalone (EXE) DataSnap server written in Delphi XE6 which I've secured with an SSL certificate using the OpenSSL DLLs. When I test the connection to the server I can see that it supports TLS v1.0. I now need to ensure the server can support TLS v1.2 (e.g. to support connections from iOS9 apps). However I can't see how to enable this. I've made the Windows registry changes to the (Windows 2008R2) server to enable TLS v1.2 but I guess this only affects IIS apps.

Can anybody show me how to enable TLS v1.2 within the Windows OpenSSL DLLs? I'm using version 1.0.2d of the DLLs. Or is there something within the DataSnap server component properties that needs to be changed?

Comment: It is something that DataSnap has to enable when it is configuring a secure connection with OpenSSL.  The DLLs implement support for TLS 1.2, but the application has to decide whether to actually use it or not.  I don't know if DataSnap allows you to enable TLS 1.2 or not.

Comment: I know this post is quite an old one, but wondering if there ever was a solution to Datasnap using TLS1.2 issue? Can't seem to find many solutions